# How to edit style in phpBB 3.1.5?

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

After switching to a new version of phpBB I found out there are a few differences. 
One of them is I don't know to edit style directly via the admin interface. I need to make some small changes like to add google analytics code or change image in the style.

In the previous version I was able to open bookmark Style and edit template directly. Is there any way to do the same in the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new versions is not possible.

> The ability to edit styles in the ACP was removed from version 3.1.0. You would have to download the file, edit it and upload it via FTP and then purge the cache in ACP, General tab.

Source: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=2270701

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit template files.

Assuming that you want to put code in footer, file you need to edit is styles/prosilver/template/overall_footer.html

Put your code before  tag, save it. Then in admin control panel click "purge cache" button.

If you want to replace some image, edit css files in styles/prosilver/theme/

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understood correctly there is no way how to change template in admin section? Do you know why I have to do changes manually instead of using old-fashion way? I mean is there any good reason why they have cancelled  such possibility?

Comment: any changes made via the ACP in 3.0.x would disappear if you clear the cache so it was removed.